# Promoting the live podcast

Tags: feature-request, podcast

It would be great if on the day of the live podcast it could be promoted in the sidebar of MSO so that those of us who are incidentally online and not clever enough to tell what time it is in another time zone can see the podcast is coming.

Five minutes before it's ready to go it could change message to something like: ON AIR now or something of the sort and the link can point to a page that has the live stream and a link to the chat room.

[image]

Comment: A banner at the top of the network metas might work, which would alert people who are currently browsing topics related to the sites that interest them. I wouldn't want to fly that on Stack Overflow, for instance, because it would probably result in an overload.

Comment: @Tim - I was thinking specifically MSO, but the per site metas would also be a good idea. But I don't think it should be limited to particular topics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [register](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/512/se-podcast-live-chat?tab=schedule) for the next podcast in the SE Podcast Live Chat room. This will notify you both in the dropdown supercollider and via email a few hours before the show.

Comment: Great, thanks. Consider me registered. However, can we have a registration for all future podcasts?

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 The only downside is that, as far as I can tell, a recurring event can't be modified once it's created. That means that if the podcast changes times or days, that the only way to change it is to delete the event and create a new one, and that has the unfortunate side effect that it removes everyone's registration. If the podcast is regular, then I'll set up a recurring event, but until then people will have to keep signing up for the next one.

Comment: Unfortunately, seems they aren't being scheduled in the chat room any more.